# To show each $f_i$ is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

so for $\Omega$ a connected open subset in $\mathbb{C}$ each $f_I \in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ for all $j = 1,2,3...n $ such that $\sum |f_j|^{2}$  is constant on $\Omega$ then I need to show that each $f_j$ is a constant on $\Omega$

so from  $\sum |f_j|^{2}$  is constant we can say that it is bounded by some $M$ so each $|f_j|^{2} \leq M $

But i dont know what next !

Comment: Hint: Try writing $f_j=u_j+v_ji$ and evaluatng $\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2}{dy^2}\right)\sum|f_j|^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lvert f_i\rvert^2=c$. If $c=0$, then we are done, so assume $c > 0$.

If $n=1$, then writing $f_1=u+iv$ with $u,\ v$ real, we note that $u^2+v^2=c$. Taking derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ we get:

$$u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 
u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0 \tag{1}$$

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y},\ 
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \tag{2}$$

we get the following:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0 \tag{3}$$

Since $\Omega$ is connected, this implies, $u = v =$ constant, i.e. $f_1 =$ constant.

For $n > 1$, choose any $w\in\Omega$ and define the holomorphic function:

$$ f(z)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(z)\overline{f_i(w)} \tag{4} $$

Then by Cauchy-Schwarz,

$$ \lvert f(z)\rvert^2\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert f_i(z)\rvert^2\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lvert f_i(w)\rvert^2\right)\leq c^2 \tag{5}$$

so that $\lvert f(z)\rvert\leq c$. But $\lvert f(w)\rvert=c$ and $w$ is an internal point of $\Omega$ so by [maximum modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle)

$$\lvert f(z)\rvert=c\ \forall\ z\in\Omega \tag{6}$$

Then $f$ is a holomorphic function on connected $\Omega$ with $\lvert f\rvert^2=$ constant, so using the $n=1$ case, we conclude $f=$ constant. Thus $f(z)=f(w)=c$.

Equation $(6)$ also implies we actually have equalities in $(5)$, and using the condition of equality in Cauchy-Schwarz, we get for all $z\in\Omega$:

$$ (f_1(z),\ldots,f_n(z))=\alpha(z)(f_1(w),\ldots,f_n(w)) \tag{7}$$

Use this to evaluate $f(z)$

$$ f(z) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(z)\overline{f_i(w)} = \alpha(z)f(w) \tag{8}$$

Using $f(z)=f(w)=c\neq 0$, we conclude $\alpha(z)=1$ for all $z\in\Omega$, so that $(7)$ implies $f_i(z)=f_i(w)$ for all $z\in\Omega$ and $1\leq i\leq n$, i.e. $f_i$'s are constant.

NOTE: This is not my solution, at least not completely. The question appeared in my Complex Analysis midterm, and professor gave a hint towards the solution, I just filled in the blanks.

Comment: Oh ! Wow ! Nice solution